# Convert PHP array from AJAX response to Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a JavaScript object based on a template I received as a test. I use Ajax to get the data from my database but i cant seem to create the object.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'fetch.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(response) {
      var test = JSON.parse(response);
      var products = {};
      for (var x = 0; x < test.length; x++) {
        products[x] = {
          productName: test[x]['name']
        };
        products[x] = {
          category: test[x]['category']
        };
        products[x] = {
          price: test[x]['price']
        };
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I'm trying to create something like this object below

```js
products = {data: [
{
  productName: "test_item_1",
  category: "category1",
  price: "49",
  image: "test_image.jpg",
},
{
  productName: "test_item_2",
  category: "category3",
  price: "99",
  image: "test_image.jpg",
},
{
  productName: "test_item_3",
  category: "category3",
  price: "29",
  image: "test_image.jpg",
},],};
```

This is the how i fetch the data from my database

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){$datas[] = $row;}echo json_encode($datas);
```

Comment: why don't you create that object from fetch.php?

Comment: Please post the JSON.

Comment: In your second codeblock, products is not properly encoded.

Comment: In PHP you can use function json_encode

Comment: Why are you POST-ing with no data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines with `products[x]` overwrite the earlier.

Change to

```js
                  products[x] = {
                      productName: test[x]['name'],
                      category: test[x]['category'],
                      price: test[x]['price'],
                  };
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of problems first...

1. The `$.ajax()` config option is `dataType`, not `datatype`
2. Specifying `dataType: "json"` means jQuery will automatically parse the response as JSON. You don't need to manually parse it again

As to your mapping problem, you can map the response array to a new one with `name` renamed to `productName` using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
$.ajax("fetch.php", {
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  // data: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}).done(data => {
  const products = {
    data: data.map(({ name: productName, category, price }) => ({
      productName,
      category,
      price
    }))
  };
});
```